# SCP from Windows Server to Linux Host

Tags: linux, powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to transfer a compressed file from a share drive to a Linux Host. However, when I use

```
 scp \\path\to\compressed\file.zip user@linuxhost:/tmp
```

the entire path gets copied to the tmp directory on the Linux Host.

Any idea how I can only transfer the filename.zip without the full path attached to it?

pscp works, but not with the keys I have generated for login without password.

Comment: Have you tried `user@linuxhost:/tmp/file.zip` as the destination?

Comment: ok, that works! (I feel dumb..) I just have to parameterize it in my build script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the full destination path:

```
scp \\path\to\compressed\file.zip user@linuxhost:/tmp/file.zip
```

Assuming you're taking the source file path as user input, you can grab the file name alone with `Split-Path`:

```
function Copy-TmpItem
{
    param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    $filename = Split-Path $Path -Leaf

    scp "'$Path'" "user@linuxhost:'/tmp/$filename'"
}
```